# java stress testing and memory

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I'm testing an application that starts a restlet, when an http request arrive to the restlet, start a new thread and proccess the request, the app creates a new object and store in a Map (
For the stress testing i'm using Jmeter, i'm seeing a problem with the java proccess memory, i dont know if the problem is the heap, the stack, or someother, lets show the problem:

I launch the same case several times, first run my project (with empty cache of course):

1. 500 threads -> the time average of threads is 1900 ms
2. 500 threads -> the time average of threads is 600 ms
3. 500 threads -> the time average of threads is 598 ms
4. 500 threads -> the time average of threads is 670 ms
   ....

As you see, my problem is that the first execution takes much longer than the others. Each thread stores in a Map the instantation object, andseems to work very slow when it is empty. anyone have any idea who might be going? i tried to increase the heap initiate memory of the jvm, but not works.
also if anyone knows any reference that can read to help me appreciate it

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your JVM didn't warm up at the first execution. Try adding `-XX:+PrintCompilation` to see whether code is being compiled in the first test, but not the second.

Comment: Thanks Peter, i add this parameter, i obtain very interesting results,now i have to studying. I've also tried to parameterize the jvm adding -Xmn100M -Xms500M -Xmx500M and the results are better and have more sense

Answer (score 1):

When performance testing Java applications you must always ensure the JVM has had time to 'warm up'. This is due to the optimisations modern JVMs (such as Oracle's [HotSpot JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) make as the code is running.

To get meaningful results you need to run through enough test cases for the times to stablise before taking a result for a given configuration/load.

See:

http://stuq.nl/weblog/2009-01-28/why-many-java-performance-tests-are-wrong

http://buytaert.net/files/oopsla07-georges.pdf

Comment: Thank for the links Malcom, they are very interesting!!